Different responses to the same requests (curl, python aiohttp) on the server and on the local host
I have a parser written in Python (aiohttp, bs4). One of the functions of the parser is to access a file by a link (example: https://modsfire.com/d/Mwv01aESgj73zx7).
import aiohttp
import yarl
import asyncio

from pprint import pprint


MODSFIRE_URL = "https://modsfire.com/"

COOKIES = {
    '_ga_JXQKZFEW04': 'GS1.1.1718453797.5.1.1718456834.0.0.0',
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.733263822.1718378970',
    'old_date': 'eyJpdiI6IlA0NXg3aDV6QVBzazFMVHRibjR3NWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC80RWt3ZHNNdEFQMks0SGhjdEltNEE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImM3Mzg4NzkyZTA5YjI5YjRiZDc2YjdkODIyMDEwNDE4MzBmZWJlYWU0MTc0ZmMxZGQxNTc0MjQyN2NlMGE1YzYifQ%3D%3D',
    'fid': 'eyJpdiI6IjFKSjJ1VDVaSHVpdmh4ZWdJcjBiZ2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicTArdExGeDdPRFpua0dVWm1vZ1pRZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNjJjZDZjZDg1NzgxODk1NmJkNmNmMDBiOTg1OWUzMTM0MmU1MjI3ODExZjkzMGRkOTBhMWVmM2RkOTJhMGM3YSJ9',
    'XSRF-TOKEN': 'eyJpdiI6ImNNM20wcjhLMnBBMW9sRG5VZm9rK1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRU9MRUVcLzExN0RiU1d2VXlXY0ExQ0tpbVwveGlDbDdiTFNpbURWSlZEZE4reEM0VlRxc1JWVFYyR3NLOTVwaGIyIiwibWFjIjoiMmUwOTNlYTIyYTkxMDZkNDJiNzY0NDE5ODY4ZDU1NGEwODMwNmIyYjZjZjliYzUxNTc3ZDZjNzA0ZGI5MTQwYiJ9',
    'modsfire_session': 'eyJpdiI6Ikxia0dmMVwvMGtSQ3VyWWJBWHRadUZ3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjNmeFBkcmtWZ0I4S3l1WDB6eGhTT2JyTnBlajlcL3pxMGlubWNRR1NvUlZHQlI5eWMxVmpPelNhTzBjYUoyVXBzIiwibWFjIjoiODg5YTE2N2UzZGI1NDRhN2QwNGFlNjk3NDEwMDNkZTY5MThkZjJiZjE5ZDIyZGNlYjNhZWM1NDY2ODg4ZWU4NyJ9',
    'referer_domain': 'eyJpdiI6ImdVM2lZYWRQdm1iNEkycXRJNGpRM3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid1NmU0F5b2NiS0JpWk4yR051YVN2QT09IiwibWFjIjoiODExMDllOGQ4ZmU1Y2RjMWVkZTIxNmFhNzhiYzNmMTFkZWNmODVmZDc5NDFlMWJhNDhlMmNmNjE2MWQzZTIwYyJ9',
    'cf_clearance': 'UFEt8KWYJuVxadyvHEgHGOcRxIzVrFYvF2h.KHdSeD8-1718456567-1.0.1.1-CmNj9kZt85DTea1QAvCxuIwwb3KzNJ96jRBsoM7r1oOOeMcNeLa3XS4osEElROQq0oely9xLAIj_U05z2sCiZg',
    'a644b2a3a3018e5f62e31f82c6db5ae0': 'eyJpdiI6Ijl6eFwvWXp3UkpUWUhYcWVqYzlDb3R3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlI2YW1FZ2JkQmIyZm9wY0FUNkVEdGc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImY5OGJlN2FkZjljZWYzNTM1ZjM5OGZjMmU1OGY0MWE2NTFiYjYyNTcwNDUzYzg1ZTJlNGNkMjc0ZmZiZjJiMTMifQ%3D%3D',
}

HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
    'Referer': MODSFIRE_URL,
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # 'Cookie': '_ga_JXQKZFEW04=GS1.1.1718453797.5.1.1718458248.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.1.733263822.1718378970; cf_clearance=UFEt8KWYJuVxadyvHEgHGOcRxIzVrFYvF2h.KHdSeD8-1718456567-1.0.1.1-CmNj9kZt85DTea1QAvCxuIwwb3KzNJ96jRBsoM7r1oOOeMcNeLa3XS4osEElROQq0oely9xLAIj_U05z2sCiZg',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Priority': 'u=1',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}


async def get_response_file(url):
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=HEADERS, cookies=COOKIES)
    response = await session.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    
    pprint(dict(response.request_info.headers))
    print("===============")
    pprint(dict(response.headers))
    if response.status != 200:
        return "Error"
            
    filename = yarl.URL(response.url).name
    response_headers = dict(response.headers)

    if filename != "d.php":
        response_headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=" + filename

    response_headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream"

    return response, response_headers


asyncio.run(get_response_file("https://modsfire.com/d/Mwv01aESgj73zx7"))

On my machine everything works - I get a 200 response. But as soon as I run this script in docker, wine or on my server - I get response 403.
On my machine the output is:
{'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImNNM20wcjhLMnBBMW9sRG5VZm9rK1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRU9MRUVcLzExN0RiU1d2VXlXY0ExQ0tpbVwveGlDbDdiTFNpbURWSlZEZE4reEM0VlRxc1JWVFYyR3NLOTVwaGIyIiwibWFjIjoiMmUwOTNlYTIyYTkxMDZkNDJiNzY0NDE5ODY4ZDU1NGEwODMwNmIyYjZjZjliYzUxNTc3ZDZjNzA0ZGI5MTQwYiJ9; '
           '_ga=GA1.1.733263822.1718378970; '
           '_ga_JXQKZFEW04=GS1.1.1718453797.5.1.1718456834.0.0.0; '
           'a644b2a3a3018e5f62e31f82c6db5ae0=eyJpdiI6Ijl6eFwvWXp3UkpUWUhYcWVqYzlDb3R3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlI2YW1FZ2JkQmIyZm9wY0FUNkVEdGc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImY5OGJlN2FkZjljZWYzNTM1ZjM5OGZjMmU1OGY0MWE2NTFiYjYyNTcwNDUzYzg1ZTJlNGNkMjc0ZmZiZjJiMTMifQ%3D%3D; '
           'cf_clearance=UFEt8KWYJuVxadyvHEgHGOcRxIzVrFYvF2h.KHdSeD8-1718456567-1.0.1.1-CmNj9kZt85DTea1QAvCxuIwwb3KzNJ96jRBsoM7r1oOOeMcNeLa3XS4osEElROQq0oely9xLAIj_U05z2sCiZg; '
           'fid=eyJpdiI6IjFKSjJ1VDVaSHVpdmh4ZWdJcjBiZ2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicTArdExGeDdPRFpua0dVWm1vZ1pRZz09IiwibWFjIjoiNjJjZDZjZDg1NzgxODk1NmJkNmNmMDBiOTg1OWUzMTM0MmU1MjI3ODExZjkzMGRkOTBhMWVmM2RkOTJhMGM3YSJ9; '
           'modsfire_session=eyJpdiI6Ikxia0dmMVwvMGtSQ3VyWWJBWHRadUZ3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjNmeFBkcmtWZ0I4S3l1WDB6eGhTT2JyTnBlajlcL3pxMGlubWNRR1NvUlZHQlI5eWMxVmpPelNhTzBjYUoyVXBzIiwibWFjIjoiODg5YTE2N2UzZGI1NDRhN2QwNGFlNjk3NDEwMDNkZTY5MThkZjJiZjE5ZDIyZGNlYjNhZWM1NDY2ODg4ZWU4NyJ9; '
           'old_date=eyJpdiI6IlA0NXg3aDV6QVBzazFMVHRibjR3NWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC80RWt3ZHNNdEFQMks0SGhjdEltNEE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImM3Mzg4NzkyZTA5YjI5YjRiZDc2YjdkODIyMDEwNDE4MzBmZWJlYWU0MTc0ZmMxZGQxNTc0MjQyN2NlMGE1YzYifQ%3D%3D; '
           'referer_domain=eyJpdiI6ImdVM2lZYWRQdm1iNEkycXRJNGpRM3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoid1NmU0F5b2NiS0JpWk4yR051YVN2QT09IiwibWFjIjoiODExMDllOGQ4ZmU1Y2RjMWVkZTIxNmFhNzhiYzNmMTFkZWNmODVmZDc5NDFlMWJhNDhlMmNmNjE2MWQzZTIwYyJ9',
 'Host': 'r3-kjxyo-modsfire.b6fbbdf4a435e192350b1c62f9bdcba7.r2.cloudflarestorage.com',
 'Priority': 'u=1',
 'Referer': 'https://modsfire.com/',
 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
 'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 '
               'Firefox/127.0'}
===============
{'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
 'CF-RAY': '8a6b98178d2d9d71-DME',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Content-Length': '3982831',
 'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
 'Date': 'Sun, 21 Jul 2024 13:38:55 GMT',
 'Etag': '"8c89e580f490fc3d9ff50098b7967cc1-1"',
 'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 20 Jul 2024 08:42:18 GMT',
 'Server': 'cloudflare',
 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
 'x-amz-mp-parts-count': '1'}

On the server, in the docker and in the wine:
# Same
===============
{'Accept-CH': 'Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, '
              'Sec-CH-UA-Mobile, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, '
              'Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA, '
              'UA-Bitness, UA-Arch, UA-Full-Version, UA-Mobile, UA-Model, '
              'UA-Platform-Version, UA-Platform, UA',
 'CF-RAY': '8a6b99d1ec1eabe6-CPH',
 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, '
                  'post-check=0, pre-check=0',
 'Connection': 'close',
 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
 'Critical-CH': 'Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, '
                'Sec-CH-UA-Mobile, Sec-CH-UA-Model, '
                'Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, '
                'Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA, UA-Bitness, UA-Arch, '
                'UA-Full-Version, UA-Mobile, UA-Model, UA-Platform-Version, '
                'UA-Platform, UA',
 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy': 'require-corp',
 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy': 'same-origin',
 'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy': 'same-origin',
 'Date': 'Sun, 21 Jul 2024 13:40:06 GMT',
 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT',
 'NEL': '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
 'Origin-Agent-Cluster': '?1',
 'Permissions-Policy': 'accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),browsing-topics=(),camera=(),clipboard-r
ead=(),clipboard-write=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=
(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-x
hr=(),usb=()',
 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin',
 'Report-To': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v4?s=BCuZckp
VeM5bhyVEA5%2FVN5jQZt%2BlyC85kdRzK0gYtoIWSBiTWJNniVedtDnL6aUGFb0lWXGCbpfw3Qywn213tqKdifufZzgb
Z8lQ4UukRLcuX%2BZI4me4bg1Xvhaedw%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
 'Server': 'cloudflare',
 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
 'X-Content-Options': 'nosniff',
 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
 'cf-chl-out': '3enpa3K5aSwfgNUzBywARRQ2ul4EUallXhghfa7HgoaNg/qNRItjRdQniZy/yLWF1RC4Ijl8j6qXQ
oKg/78SoT6Q31iobZKau7Yv0T6d8p7j1McT6tBUCvZp3uUAYWl06ktHE67A2m//cyNFHnbQTa93JyyGZ3d9sjFZ4UH0rA
E=$My/VujbV2w+XBN0G4CEg3w==',
 'cf-mitigated': 'challenge'}

My machine:
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
WM: bspwm
Kernel: 6.9.10-zen1-1-zen

Python 3.12.4
aiohttp==3.9.5

curl 8.8.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.8.0 OpenSSL/3.3.1 zlib/1.3.1 brotli/1.1.0 zstd/1.5.6 libidn2/2.3.7 libpsl/0.21.5 libssh2/1.11.0 nghttp2/1.62.1 nghttp3/1.4.0
Release-Date: 2024-05-22

Docker version 27.0.3, build 7d4bcd863a

wine-9.13

Characteristics of my server:
enter image description here

I was able to run the script in wine, using my computer as a proxy (using mitmproxy).
I've also tried using public proxies - didn't help
The curl request to url works on my machine, and on my server (the answers the same), but in docker it doesn't:
Curl command:

curl '<url>' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd' -H 'Referer: https://modsfire.com/' -L -v

Docker command:
docker run --rm curlimages/curl 'https://modsfire.com/d/Mwv01aESgj73zx7' -H 'User-A
gent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd' -H 'Referer: https://modsfire.com/' -L -v

Response in docker:
* IPv6: 2a06:98c1:3122:e000::, 2a06:98c1:3123:e000::
* IPv4: 188.114.98.224, 188.114.99.224
*   Trying 188.114.98.224:443...
* Connected to modsfire.com (188.114.98.224) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
*  CAfile: /cacert.pem
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4154 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [79 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 / X25519 / id-ecPublicKey
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=modsfire.com
*  start date: May 29 03:12:54 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 27 03:12:53 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "modsfire.com" matched cert's "modsfire.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=E1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
*   Certificate level 0: Public key type EC/prime256v1 (256/128 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384
*   Certificate level 1: Public key type EC/secp384r1 (384/192 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384
*   Certificate level 2: Public key type EC/secp384r1 (384/192 Bits/secBits), signed using ecdsa-with-SHA384
} [5 bytes data]
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://modsfire.com/d/Mwv01aESgj73zx7
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: modsfire.com]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /d/Mwv01aESgj73zx7]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [referer: https://modsfire.com/]
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /d/Mwv01aESgj73zx7 HTTP/2
> Host: modsfire.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:127.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/127.0
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
> Referer: https://modsfire.com/
> 
* Request completely sent off
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [230 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [230 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 403 
< date: Sun, 21 Jul 2024 13:38:00 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< accept-ch: Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Mobile, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA, UA-Bitness, UA-Arch, UA-Full-Version, UA-Mobile, UA-Model, UA-Platform-Version, UA-Platform, UA
< critical-ch: Sec-CH-UA-Bitness, Sec-CH-UA-Arch, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Mobile, Sec-CH-UA-Model, Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version, Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List, Sec-CH-UA-Platform, Sec-CH-UA, UA-Bitness, UA-Arch, UA-Full-Version, UA-Mobile, UA-Model, UA-Platform-Version, UA-Platform, UA
< cross-origin-embedder-policy: require-corp
< cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
< cross-origin-resource-policy: same-origin
< origin-agent-cluster: ?1
< permissions-policy: accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),browsing-topics=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()
< referrer-policy: same-origin
< x-content-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< cf-mitigated: challenge
< cf-chl-out: KHfPV3kjAY1jb1FNEnUvyKvyMVLML41D/a6xL2gye+3Cu93GAZKtKzdRjuCtLK+N5dIsaUuLj4W/YtllqUwqxApBWZvh3mNcu+h1r0+7SE9oymrfiLv43SJpqzBn0TBL1y3Vr02nNBjFRvyaY8ELJA==$y8fX1XwUkq1ES/25ev0iRQ==
< cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
{ [5 bytes data]
< report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=nyb5KfWPFBTwPJQjkO64edjYPXs2V3X1SWQMMU8Al4M91hTEz%2Fo6L098YqRfGjIqator%2FimNVjm9E%2BoYnylQHhZy2ambz4mL2jTDHP283Ux%2F9V6V5%2BvDOH672349CA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 8a6b96c18ca19d8b-DME
< content-encoding: br
< 
{ [5 bytes data]

Why does the curl request work but the python script on aiohttp does not (on my server)?

If you're running the exact same code in different environments and in some of them it gets an error, is this possibly an issue with the remote host rather than your code?  Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include the response as plain text, especially in the failing case?  Can you give a little more description of a single failing environment; if it fails locally in Docker, for example, how are you building the image and running the container?
